# Convert two different date formats to one consistent format in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, automation, powercli

I am automating the reading of log files and have noticed that some log files have dates shown as 2016-12-19 while others would have the same date as Jul 28 11.

Thus far, I have successfully extracted both dates to come out as above. I need to convert both to the same format (either YYYY-MM-DD or anything else). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell uses objects, so you can cast those date-like strings to `[DateTime]` objects. Example:

```
PS C:\> $dateTime = [DateTime] "2016-12-19"
PS C:\> $dateTime
Monday, December 19, 2016 12:00:00 AM
PS C:\> "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" -f $dateTime
12/19/2016
```

You can even shorten this:

```
PS C:\> "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" -f ([DateTime] "2016-12-19")
12/19/2016
```

(`-f` is PowerShell's string format operator.)

Comment: Thanks, the [DateTime] trick seemed to work. My only question is, how can I make this generic? For example, to work with all dates and to convert them. For instance, I have July 28 11 and Dec 11 16 as the $DateTime variable (it will change after each iteration in my loop).

Comment: Give them a try: `[DateTime] "Jul 28 11"` and `[DateTime] "Dec 11 16"` will output `[DateTime]` objects.

Comment: Yes I understand that but that would be hardcoding it. I need a way to do it generically, for any date without explicitly specifying it.

Comment: You can pass as a string variable. Look at the first example in my answer.

Comment: Cool, I believe that works. Is there a way to just display the last 2 digits of the year? Such as 02/24/16 instead of 02/24/2016

Comment: Change the format string to however you want to output it: `MM-dd-yy` would format the date as month-day-year.

Comment: Right now, I am passing in the string as $FinalDate = [DateTime] "$FinalDate", which returns me 02/11/2016 for example. How would I pass in a string to specify that I want 2/11/16 as the result? (Get rid of the 0 and the 20 in the year)

Comment: [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) will be helpful here.

Comment: @ninchicken What default format is used for output of a \[datetime\] depends on your own current settings. See `(get-culture).DateTimeFormat`